cannot statfs : permission denied about gvfs
Why my Log have "cannot statfs : permission denied" about gvfs every five minutes.
Ubuntu (20.04) is set to close the GUI, used sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target  Code, Does it have anything to do with this? What's the solution?
